# amCharts - How to add description to each line in multiple lines chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I want to add the description for each value when move to each date, e.g: beside the value point (number) of each line for one date, I can see other description also (example: some explanation for this value).

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-value-axes/#theme-light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use graph's [`balloonText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#balloonText) for that.

If the same description needs to appear for all balloons withing the same graph, you can just enter it into balloonText. I.e.:

```
"graphs": [{
    "title": "red line",
    "valueField": "visits",
    "balloonText": "Graph description. Value: [[value]]"
}, ...
```

Or, if you need to display a separate description for each category/datapoint, you can include that in your data as a separate field, and reference to it via the [[metacode]]. I.e.:

```
"graphs": [{
    "title": "red line",
    "valueField": "visits",
    "balloonText": "Value: [[value]]; Description: [[description]]"
}, ...
```

The above will look for a "description" property in the current data point and will display it in the place of `[[description]]` on the balloon.